# Changing props from child in parent Vuejs

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

So I have a *Tabs.vue* component with four tabs:

```
<template>
.
.
      <v-tab href="#tab-1" @click="showFirstTabFunc">
        First Tab
        <v-icon>check_box_outline_blank</v-icon>
      </v-tab>

      <v-tab href="#tab-2" @click="showSecondTabFunc">
        Second Tab
        <v-icon>indeterminate_check_box</v-icon>
      </v-tab>

      <v-tab href="#tab-3" @click="showThirdTabFunc">
        Third Tab
        <v-icon>memory</v-icon>
      </v-tab>

      <v-tab href="#tab-4" @click="showTabFourFunc">
        Fourth Tab
        <v-icon>list_alt</v-icon>
      </v-tab>
.
.   
</template>

<script>
.
.
  methods:{
   showFirstTabFunc(){
   },
   showSecondTabFunc(){
   },
   showThirdTabFunc(){
   },
   showFourthTabFunc(){
   },
.
.
</script>
```

Now I have the parent component *App.vue* which contains:

```
<template>
.
.
   <app-tabs></app-tabs>
.
.
</template>

<script>
    import Tabs from "./Tabs.vue";
    export default {
      data() {
        return {
         showFirstTab: false,
         showSecondTab: false,
         showThirdTab: false,
         showTabFour: false,
         }
        },
       components:{
        appTabs: Tabs
        }
     }
</script>
```

My goal is to click on let's say First Tab in *Tabs.vue* and by doing so changing the "showFirstTab" from false to true in *App.vue*. And then if I click on the second tab in *Tabs.vue* "showFirstTab" in *App.vue* becomes false and "showSecondTab" becomes true and so on.

P.S yes I have to keep those props in the parent component.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can [emit event](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html) to parent

```
showFirstTabFunc () {
  this.$emit('setActiveTab', 'showFirstTab')
}
```

In Parent

```
<app-tabs @setActiveTab="setActiveTab"></app-tabs>

methods: {
  setActiveTab (activeTab) {
    this.showFirstTab = false
    this.showSecondTab = false
    this.showThirdTab = false
    this.showTabFour = false
    this[activeTab] = true
  }
}
```